# WMI Provider Host (WmiPrvSE.exe) + ntdll.dll = nonstop 15% CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I've tried everything that I could think of, but I just can't solve this one. The WmiPrvSE.exe process + ntdll.dll eats up to 15% of my CPU (Dual-Core E6700 @ 3.20GHz) on my PC the whole time. I tried suspending the service, restarting it, uninstalling recently installed programs etc. Still the same..

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit.

Here's a screenshot from Process Explorer:

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you run the [WMI Diagnostic utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7684)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [rebuild your WMI repository](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx).